Error al querer iniciar en Kubernetes
Tengo un error al querer iniciar en Kubernetes, me marca algo asi:
* minikube v1.34.0 en Microsoft Windows 11 Home 10.0.26100.2033 Build 26100.2033
E1023 22:53:47.989266    7868 start.go:812] api.Load failed for minikube: filestore "minikube": Docker machine "minikube" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
E1023 22:53:47.989266    7868 start.go:812] api.Load failed for minikube: filestore "minikube": Docker machine "minikube" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
* Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
* Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
* Creando virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Creando virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

X Saliendo por un error HOST_VIRT_UNAVAILABLE: Failed to start host: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Suggestion: Virtualization support is disabled on your computer. If you are running minikube within a VM, try '--driver=docker'. Otherwise, consult your systems BIOS manual for how to enable virtualization.
* Related issues:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4730 

Esto sucede al querer iniciar con el comando:
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --insecure-registry="10.0.0.0/24"

Mi equipo es una ASUS RoG Strix G16, tengo activada la virtualizacion, tengo instalado el virtual box y docker, no tengo instalado Hyper-V y no se porque me sigue dando ese error, Ya intente de todo, desde apagar la virtualizacion en la bios, hasta intentar hacerlo con docker y demas, son para mis clases de universidad y si alguien tuvo el mismo error y lo soluciono por favor ayuda :(

Dentro del error, te dice 3 veces:
This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

Traducido al español:
Esta computadora no tiene VT-X/AMD-v habilitado. Habilitarlo en el BIOS es obligatorio.

En pocas palabras, sí o sí tienes que tener activada la opción de virtualización desde la BIOS.
Como dato adicional, aquí una guía en los foros oficiales de Asus:
https://www.asus.com/us/support/faq/1045141/
